# Devise authenticate_user! fails with POST / DELETE REST calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise to authenticate user via the standard implementation. Once a user logs in, he/she can call an REST API that uses the same controller (and thus also Devise). The controller looks like this:

```
class FriendController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def create
    ...
  end
  def destroy
    ...
  end
  def index
    ...
  end
end
```

I got the index action to work with authenticated_user!. In this case, if a user is authenticated, index will return data with 200 Status Code. If a user isn't authenticated, `index` returns `Unauthorized` with 40x Status Code.

However, when I'm calling `create` or `destroy` via POST and DELETE, it automatically logs me out of the application and returns 40x Unauthorized error. Anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Here's the route.rb

```
  resources :users do
    resources :friends, only: [:index, :friended_me, :create, :destroy]
  end
```

For example, does this needs to be within `devise_scope :users` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why this is happening. In `ApplicationController`, if `protect_from_forgery` is enabled. The API calls for `POST/PUT/DELETE` will check for `auth_token`. If it's not provided, it'll fail. However, for `GET`, if it's not provided, the action will still proceed if user is logged in.

The fix is to use the auth_token generated by `resource.reset_authentication_token!` after overriding `SessionsController#create`